# specify medium in emptydir

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

according to the doc https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir the volumes will be stored according to node's setting. Currently I am seeing the memory usage is pretty high in my case. I suspect that the default setting for the node is using "Memory". Is there a way to specify the volume to be mounted on other storage like disk?

Answer (score 2):

EmptyDir won't use memory unless you specifically set the `emptyDir.medium` field to `Memory` in each Pod's manifest.
Try executing `free -m` to confirm your current system doesn't consume shared memory too much:

```
# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          31958        4680       21795        1079        5482       25781
```